# Capture screencast of rspec selenium browser test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

Is it possible to take a screencast of the firefox browser screens as they are controlled by a capybara test with the selenium web driver?

I looked at the sauce driver ([1](http://saucelabs.com)) but wasn't too sure about the set up.

I guess I could just maximize the browser window and take a screencast of my monitor, but thought I would check if there's a tool for the browser screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mentioned SauceLabs, but that's probably the best way. You could build your own mechanism but it will likely take a fair bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'Launchy' gem: https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy

It allows you to add the line: 'save_and_open_page' to your capybara tests and will open up that page as it looks at that point in the browser.

So just install the launchy gem, and you can add it to the middle of your capybara test. For example:

```
visit root_path
save_and_open_page
fill_in ... rest of test ...
```

Comment: Yes I do use that thanks, but I'm looking for something to record the browser page actions and play them back as a video